# What does the string parameter represent in "TryUpdateModelAsyncAsync<TModel>(TModel, String, IValueProvider)"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.tryupdatemodelasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0) with no examples it is:

> **prefix**
>
> String
>
> The prefix to use when looking up values in the current
>    IValueProvider.

### Razor

In the ms docs [razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud) pages example the calls are made using the object that the posted form represents:
The Create.cshtml.cs file which contains

```
[BindProperty]
public Student Student { get; set; }
```

and calls:

```
await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
            studentToUpdate,
            "student",
            s => s.FirstMidName, s => s.LastName, s => s.EnrollmentDate))
```

The Create.cshtml page has a form:

```
@page
@model ContosoUniversity.Pages.Students.CreateModel

<form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

### MVC

In the [mvc page tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud), calls are made with the empty string. What does this string actually represent?

```
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
        studentToUpdate,
        "",
        s => s.FirstMidName, s => s.LastName, s => s.EnrollmentDate))
```

As answered in the comments, here the model IS a student in Create.cshtml:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Student
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: For cases where you have complex nested objects. e.g. you generating say `@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Student.LastName)` because your model contains a property named `Student` which is a complex object.

Comment: @Stephen Ahh. Ok. I'll add the html so future readers might understand now too.